# for what value of $r$ does the sequence and series converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $a_n = \dfrac{4^n}{n^3} + (r^2)^n $ and $$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4^n}{n^3+(r^2)^n}$$
I think that the denominator $> 0$ as $n\to\infty$, but that doesn't seem right. please help me with this problem: when is this sequence and series converge?
i divided the numerator and denminator by $4^n$ but i'm unable to proceed forward to find a general vale of r for which the sequence and series converge

Comment: 1. pls use the dollar sign with your formula... 2. Please include your efforts of solving this problem. 3. The role of $r$ in $\{a_n\}$ is ambiguous. So please clarify the question.

Comment: an is the sequence and S is the series

Answer (score 1):

You can write $$a_n=\frac{1}{\frac{n^3}{4^n}+\left(\frac r2\right)^{2n}},$$ so that as $n\to\infty$ we find that $\frac{n^3}{4^n}\to 0.$ On the other hand, if $|r|<2,$ then $$\left(\frac r2\right)^{2n}\to 0$$ as well, so that then $a_n\to\infty.$ However, for $|r|\ge 2,$ we find that $$\left(\frac r2\right)^{2n}=1$$ or $$\left(\frac r2\right)^{2n}\to \infty,$$ and convergence of $a_n$ follows in either of the last cases.

If follows that for the series $S$ to exist, you must have $|r|>2.$ However, that may be insufficient for convergence of the series. For more delicate analysis, note that $$a_n<\left(\frac{2}{r}\right)^{2n}$$ for large $n,$ so that upon applying the root test we see that $S$ exists exactly whenever $|r|>2.$